# Как сделать клик по элементу кроме одного блока в JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется код html:

```
<div id="touchSideSwipe" class="touch-side-swipe d-lg-none">
...
<button class="user_region1">Не выбрано <span class="arrow1">&#8595;</span></button>
</div>
```

Как добавить событие на **touchSideSwipe**, но чтобы она не отрабатывала на button **user_region1**? Я пытался, у меня не получилось:

```
const box = $(".touch-side-swipe");
box.on("click", function (e){
    if (!$('.user_region1'))
    {
        console.log('hi');
    }
    console.log('123');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве альтернативы )

Если нужно задействовать именно параметр event на onClick элемента, через него можно проверить наличие у самого элемента необходимого класса, и завязать на него условие:

```
const box = $(".touch-side-swipe");
box.on("click", function (e){
    if (e.target.classList.contains('user_region1'))
    {
        console.log('hi');
        return false;
    }
    console.log('123');
})
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего проверить на наличие определённого класса, если его нет, то ничего делать не будем.

```
// Кроме класса .user_region1
if(!$(this).hasClass('user_region1')) {
  // ...
}
```

Демо:

```js
$('#touchSideSwipe').on('click', 'button', function() {
  if(!$(this).hasClass('user_region1')) {
    console.log('click');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="touchSideSwipe" class="touch-side-swipe d-lg-none">
  <button>A</button>
  <button>B</button>
  <button>C</button>
  <button class="user_region1">Не выбрано <span class="arrow1">&#8595;</span></button>
</div>
```